Given $a,b,c,d$ in arithmetic progression, can we express the solution to $\frac1{x-a}+\frac1{x-b}+\frac1{x-c}+\frac1{x-d}=0$ in terms of $a,d$ only?
Context
This is a question I wrote for myself recently, heavily based on an old (1930s) examination paper for university admissions.

Given $a,b,c,d$ which are real numbers and consecutive terms in an arithmetic progression, can we solve the equation $\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}+\frac{1}{x-c}+\frac{1}{x-d}=0$ expressing $x$ in terms of $a,d$ only?

The solution I wrote at the time is here - I do feel though that a more efficient solution is possible.
Solution attempt 1
Since $b-a=c-b=a-d$ we can write $b=\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{2}{3}d$ and $c=\frac{2}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}d$.
From here, I can multiply both sides by $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=(x-a)(x-\frac{1}{3}a-\frac{2}{3}d)(x-\frac{2}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}d)(x-d)$ to obtain a cubic (since the linear terms cancel before summing the LHS) in $x$.
After some algebra work, three solutions are found:
$x=\frac{a+d}{2},x=\frac{1}{6}((3+\sqrt{5})a+(3-\sqrt{5})d)$ and $x=\frac{1}{6}((3-\sqrt{5})a+(3+\sqrt{5})d)$.
A different approach?
Since $a,b,c,d$ are consecutive terms, the (arithmetic) mean of $a,d$ and the mean of $b,c$ will be the same number. Call this number $m$, so we have $\frac{a+d}{2}=m$ and $\frac{b+c}{2}=m$.
Can this be used to find a more efficient solution?
Is there an even simpler solution that I have missed?

Once you have $b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$ and $d$, you've shown that the answer to "Can we solve [...] in terms of $a,d$ only?" is "Yes". :)

Fair point! Assuming the solution is valid, of course. I think it is but far wiser come here.

Answering "Yes" means that you don't have to find the explicit solutions (and risk getting them wrong). Just move on to the next question. :)

Continuing OP's "different approach" ... Define mean $m:=\frac12(a+d)$ and half-step $h:=\frac16(d-a)$. Then
$$a = m-3h \qquad b = m- h \qquad c = m + h \qquad d = m + 3 h \tag1$$
and the equation becomes
$$\frac1{x-m+3h}+\frac1{x-m+h}+\frac1{x-m-h}+\frac1{x-m-3h}=0 \tag2$$
Defining $y:=x-m$ and rearranging, this is
$$\frac1{y+h}+\frac1{y-h}+\frac1{y+3h}+\frac1{y-3h}=0 \tag3$$
$$\frac{2y}{y^2-h^2}+\frac{2y}{y^2-9h^2}=0 \tag4$$
$$4y(y^2-5h^2)=0 \tag5$$
So, the roots are $y=0$ and $y=\pm h\sqrt5$; that is,
$$x=m = \frac12(a+d) \qquad x=m\pm h\sqrt5=\frac12(a+d)\pm \frac16(d-a)\sqrt5 \tag6$$
which agrees with OP's solution. $\square$

If $t=b-a$ then \begin{align}b&=a+t\\
c&=a+2t\\
d&=a+3t
\end{align}
Now join first and last term and second and third together. So we have $${2x-2a-3t\over (x-a)(x-d)} + {2x-2a-3t\over (x-b)(x-c)}=0$$
so we have $ x_1={2a+3t\over 2} = {a+d\over 2}$ and $$(x-a)(x-d)+(x-b)(x-c)=0$$
i.e. $$x^2-(2a+3t)x+a^2+3at+t^2=0$$ which discirimant is $D=5t^2$. The rest is easy.

Very nice. Thanks. I initially thought (and this answer has confirmed) that the choice of $a,d$ is relatively arbitrary, and we could express $x$ just as easily in terms of $b,c$ as well. I also like the reduction to a quadratic - I was working with a cubic which made the algebra more complicated.
